# Parameter error in tmaptools package read osm when using example data

Tags: r, tmap

Getting error with `read_osm` from the `tmaptools package in R`. Want to generate a static map with background layer.

Error is present even when using the example `NLD_muni` data from tmap package

```
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)
library(OpenStreetMap)
tmap_mode("plot")
data(NLD_muni)
test <- tmaptools::read_osm(NLD_muni, type = "esri", zoom = NULL)
```

**Error**

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
>     Sorry, parameter type `NA' is ambiguous or not supported.

Expected to load a *basemap*

Could use `tmap_mode("view")` and created interactive plot but ideally can make a static plot.

Comment: Can you show what is `NLD_mundi`?

Comment: NLD_muni is the example sf data provided in tmap. I've updated the code section to show how to load it. NLD_muni:                                             NLD_muni
Simple feature collection with 403 features and 14 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 13565.4 ymin: 306846.9 xmax: 277992.8 ymax: 619292
epsg (SRID):    28992
proj4string:    +proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=565.2369,50.0087,465.658,-0.406857,0.350733,-1.87035,4.0812 +units=m +no_defs

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem as you, the examples from the help files don't work anymore for `read_osm` depending on the help file (this since I upgraded to Windows 10 and reinstalled R - I suspect it is related).

I have found [another example](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tmap/versions/1.2/topics/read_osm) on the web which is working for me, and from which you can hopefully start again.

```
# load Netherlands shape
data(NLD_muni)

# read OSM raster data
osm_NLD <- read_osm(bb(NLD_muni, ext=1.1, projection ="longlat"))

# plot with regular tmap functions
tm_shape(osm_NLD) +
    tm_raster() +
    tm_shape(NLD_muni) +
    tm_polygons("population", convert2density=TRUE, style="kmeans", alpha=.7, palette="Purples")
```

Comment: Including the basemap in a static map is a powerful tool. This code was working in an earlier version of tmaptools and is not working in the current version 2.3-1 -- I've opened a GitHub issue https://github.com/mtennekes/tmaptools/issues/19

Comment: I agree, thanks for opening an issue! I had a whole script working perfectly before the update which I had to modify, so there has clearly been a change

Answer (score 1):

In order to generate a static base map in tmap using `read_osm`, the `x` argument object needs to be in the WGS84 projection (EPSG 4326).

```
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)
library(tidyverse)

tmap_mode("plot")

data(NLD_muni)

# This does not work:
NLD_bm <- tmaptools::read_osm(NLD_muni, type = "esri")

# The problem is that NLD_muni is in the projected coordinate system for Netherlands,
# but read_osm wants WGS84
sf::st_crs(NLD_muni) # check the coordinate reference system

# This does work
NLD_bm <- NLD_muni %>% 
  sf::st_transform(., crs = 4326) %>% # transform NLD_muni to WGS84 projection
  sf::st_bbox(.) %>% # extract bounding box of transformed layer
  tmaptools::read_osm(., type = "esri") # pass bounding box to read_osm

# Now you can map them
tm_shape(NLD_bm) + tm_rgb() + tm_shape(NLD_muni) + tm_borders(col = "red")
```

Here is what it looks like:
[image: static map with OSM basemap]

Answer (score 0):

Two comments:

1) it is not doable to show a basemap with a static {tmap} map; the basemap functionality comes from {leaflet} package, and is therefore available only in view mode.

If you absolutely positively require a basemap in a static map (which is a valid use case) consider using a combination of {ggplot2} and {ggmap}.

2) your loading of `NLD_muni` is needlesly complex; consider this code instead:

```
library(tmap)

data(NLD_muni)

tmap_mode("view")

tm_shape(NLD_muni) + tm_polygons(col = "population")
```

[image]